# Reverse bit operation in objective-c / c++

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I have opposite question for

If i have:

```
typedef enum {
    SUNDAY = (1 << 0),
    MONDAY = (1 << 1),
    TUESDAY = (1 << 2),
    WEDNESDAY = (1 << 3),
    THURSDAY = (1 << 4),
    FRIDAY = (1 << 5),
    SATURDAY = (1 << 6),
} PFDateDays;
```

And my input is `65` for example `(SUNDAY,SATURDAY)` there is a clever way for etract this values from enum?

Here is my method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)selectFromMyEnum {
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int myInput = 62;
    NSArray *enumArray = @[@(SATURDAY),@(FRIDAY),@(THURSDAY),@(WEDNESDAY),@(TUESDAY),@(MONDAY),@(SUNDAY)];
    for(NSNumber *numberInEnumArray in enumArray) {
        if(myInput >= [numberInEnumArray integerValue]) {
            [returnArray addObject:numberInEnumArray];
            myInput -= [numberInEnumArray integerValue];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",returnArray);
    return returnArray;
}
```

And this is output:

```
(
    64, //SATURDAY
    1 //SUNDAY
)
```

So this is correct. But maybe there is method I don't know about that allow me to do this without this pointless assign enum to array etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the first thing that comes to my mind is this.  Since your enum is nicely laid out for flagging you can do something like this:

Start with your highest enum value (SATURDAY) and use a bitwise and (`&`) to check if your value contains it.  Then shift the comparison value right by 1 and repeat until your comparison value is zero.

```
PFDateDays comparison = SATURDAY;

//If your enum doesn't end at 1 like the above example,
//you could also use >= SUNDAY
while(((int)comparison) > 0) {
    if((myVal & comparison) == comparison)
        //Do what you want, this value is valid

    comparison = comparison >> 1;
}
```

Comment: `if(myVal & comparison) { ...` would do.

Comment: @HermannKlecker True!  In some languages that doesn't fly so it's really just my habit.  It's also more robust for checking more then one flag at once.  In this case, though, you are right.